# XSLT concat Issue?

Tags: xml, xslt

Pls any one help me to concat 'Img' and "<" or ">" signs in xslt

have to look "`Img>`"  OR "`<Img`"

**Update from comments:**

> ```
> <Content><![CDATA[<P>dfsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsd</P>
>                   <P><IMG alt="" hspace=0 
>                           src="../../Repository.aspx?uri=4343"
>                           border=0></P>
>                   <P>fdsfsdfsdfsdf</P>
>                   <P>fdsfd</P>]]></Content>
> ```

This is the xml and I want to get the text without img tags.

My XSLT code is just like this:

> ```
>  <xsl:param name="text" select="."/> 
>  <xsl:if test=". != ''"> 
>   <xsl:choose> 
>    <xsl:when test="contains($text, 'IMG')"> 
>     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'IMG')" 
>                   disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
>     <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'border=0')" 
>                   disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
>    </xsl:when>
>    <xsl:otherwise>
>     <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
>    </xsl:otherwise>
>   </xsl:choose>
>  </xsl:if>
> ```

Comment: Please provide shortened XML input and desired output. Thus you will be able to get an exhaustive answer much faster.

Comment: **This is FAQ**: the content of CDATA sections is **unparsed text**. So, there is no `IMG` element. **You should never expect unparsed data behaves like parsed data.**

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '&lt;IMG')" />
```

Comment: thanks machooo ! I earlier try out this one but didnt work suppose space inbetween img and &lt; Any Way thanks all of u involving to solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to generate an `<img/>` tag, use `<xsl:element name="img"/>`. For instance:

```
<xsl:element name="img">
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="$the_image_url"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: It's rather verbose, especially in xml-html transformation. <code><img src="{$the_image_url}"/></code> is much cleaner.

Comment: @Flack: +1. That's a shorter option, if applicable (if the tag name is known, and the attribute is in a variable).

Comment: THanks for the quick reply but my issue is not suitable for your answer 
<Content>
   <![CDATA[<P>dfsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsd</P>
<P><IMG alt="" hspace=0 src="../../Repository.aspx?uri=4343" border=0></P>
<P>fdsfsdfsdfsdf</P>
<P>fdsfd</P>]]></Content>
    this is the xml and i want to get the text without img tags??

Comment: @Victor Nicollet, what's with the variable? Any xpath expression could be used. xsl:attribute is rather necessary if you have some if-else statement.

Comment: no sir , my XSLT code is just like this <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
 
  <xsl:if test=". != ''">

   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text, 'IMG')">
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, 'IMG')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text, 'border=0')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>

   </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:if>

Comment: i just want the text not include with in the <img> tag i try with <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, 'IMG')" /> but it return with "<" sign with all other text ?? Pls help

Comment: Please add this as edit to your question. Properly formatted syntax is much easier to understand.